# Cannot compile Rust code that calls C code which calls vsnprintf on Windows

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to compile Rust code on Windows that calls `vsnprintf`.  My C code looks like this:

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// A static buffer for storing any formatted messages.
static char buffer[4096];

void rust_logger(const char *fmt, ...) {
    // Reconstruct the variable arguments as a va_list.  This is necessary so we 
    // can chain together a call to vsnprintf.
    va_list varargs;
    va_start(varargs, fmt);

    // Write the formatted string to our target (static) buffer.
    vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, fmt, varargs);

    // Call Rust back with final string
    ...

    // Clean up processing of variable arguments
    va_end(varargs);
}
```

This works fine on macOS (and I would guess under Linux, although I have not tried it).  But on Windows, I'm having problems.  The error I get is:

```
 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\amd64\\link.exe" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\lib\\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\lib\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt\\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\lib\\winv6.3\\um\\x64" "/NOLOGO" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\Source\\rust-fmu\\target\\debug\\deps\\rust_fmu-dd167e2c1e3583f1.0.o" "/OUT:C:\\Users\\mtiller\\Source\\rust-fmu\\target\\debug\\deps\\rust_fmu-dd167e2c1e3583f1.exe" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\mtiller\\Source\\rust-fmu\\target\\debug\\deps" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\mtiller\\Source\\rust-fmu\\target\\debug\\build\\rust-fmu-e434516f4288772d\\out" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "logger.lib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\Source\\rust-fmu\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblibloading-c41a2f71457b39f3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\Source\\rust-fmu\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblibc-5dc7b85e748840b4.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\Source\\rust-fmu\\target\\debug\\deps\\libkernel32-835ed4d4f4dc2d3e.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\Source\\rust-fmu\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinapi-a5898d7aceb63fac.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-90fbcc8c07b4a644.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-d2e7baf2c0a36eaf.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-112baa0117a60076.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-ad15457034b2bf37.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librand-fa1852079e0fefd1.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcollections-27e4c8cc19e6faac.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-588bb0bd8c9dd8ca.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc_system-dbfe715efb71d408.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd_unicode-a2e15800b52a7a60.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-b2880fdfb9b2b596.rlib" "C:\\Users\\mtiller\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-9d27746f5ba8488f.rlib" "kernel32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "shell32.lib" "msvcrt.lib"
 note: logger.lib(logger.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __ms_vsnprintf referenced in function vsnprintf
          C:\Users\mtiller\Source\rust-fmu\target\debug\deps\rust_fmu-dd167e2c1e3583f1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

From my research, it seems like this has something to do with some mismatch between MinGW and MinGW64, but when I look at the output of the Rust build, it seems to be using Visual Studio 14.0.

I'm totally confused.  I don't quite know how Rust determines which toolchain to use.  I used the `rustup-init.exe` installer which I assumed would "do the right thing", but it seems confused here (or is it just me).

Any suggestions on how to get my toolchain aligned?  One other constraint is that I'm using the `libloading` crate because my program is loading DLLs. I want that part to work as well, but haven't gotten to test that under Windows yet because of build issues.

P.S. - I need the `v` version of `vsnprintf` because I'm getting passed varargs and I need a way to actually process them.

Comment: Rust doesn't "determine" the toolchain to use; you do. You choose to install a version of Rust that uses the MSVC toolchain or the GNU toolchain, and you can tell which you have by running `rustc -v --verbose`.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to reproduce your problem. Please review how to create a [MCVE] (taking special note of *minimal* and *verifiable*). For example, you do not show how the C code is being compiled or linked, or the Rust code that calls it.

Comment: You wrote `rustc -v --verbose`, but I assume you meant `rustc -V --verbose`.  That says I'm using `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`.  So it is odd that I'm getting this error that seems to be related to MinGW.  But at least now I know what host it is using.  I'll work the problem from there.  It is hard to provide a verifiable case here because I'm pretty sure this has to do with the tools that are installed on my computer.

Comment: You say that Rust doesn't "determine" the toolchain.  Note that the Rustup installation notes say "Despite being built against the GNU toolchain, the Windows build of rustup will install Rust for the MSVC toolchain if it detects that MSVC is installed."  That is what I was referring to.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to be precise (and not doing a good job of it). The *Rust compiler* does not determine which toolchain to use. Rustup will pick a toolchain-specific version of the compiler to install for you if you don't specify, but tools built around the compiler aren't Rust *per se*. Even if you can't provide a verifiable example, you can update with additional information and the community can try and help as best we can. For example, if you've compiled your C code to an object with the MinGW toolchain, that would be a key factor.

Answer (score 0):

My machine had MSVC, MinGW64 and MinGW installed on it.  Given the error messages, I fell into the trap of thinking that it was related to `rustc` invoking the wrong compiler/linker because of issues in my path or its own assumptions about the tools on my machine.

It turns out the build script I was using was calling `gcc` and `ar` directly, which invoked the MinGW commands.  I thought Rust had "wrappers" for these commands so they behaved the same on all platforms (hence my lack of concern about these).

When I read the [documentation on build scripts](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) more closely, I see that they repeat the same (non-portable) approach, but then talk about the lack of cross-platform support for that approach and then show a much simpler and more portable way to do this.

Bottom line, use:

```
[build-dependencies]
gcc = "0.3"
```

...and read the build script documentation carefully. Now everything compiles fine on both macOS and Windows.